# Java issues in OSX Mavericks

Tags: macos, java, osx-mavericks

I seem to have a java problem on my MBP (OSX 10.9.2), possibly related to the Mavericks upgrade.  When trying to activate a newly installed SSH process I get:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: <myprocess>
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: <myprocess>
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
```

The developer of the SSH process thinks my Java setup is the problem.  My `java -version` is:

```
java version "1.6.0_65"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_65-b14-462-11M4609)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 20.65-b04-462, mixed mode)
```

`echo $CLASSPATH` returns nothing (an empty line).  But running `set CLASSPATH=/Library/Java/Extensions` (which I gather is the right path) has no effect.  But even if it did, my system has nothing in that folder - so should it?

Very grateful for assistance.

Comment: Does updating to Java 7 from Oracle solve the problem? Apple sort of abandoned (er...deeply deprecated) its old Java 6 version.

Comment: I've installed Java 7 but `java -version` reports the same version as above.

Answer (score 0):

Solved.  [This SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12757558/installed-java-7-on-mac-os-x-but-terminal-is-still-using-version-6) has the answer - Ákos's answer (but credit belongs to @viktor-lexington if anyone wants someone to thank).  The process I followed is:

```
$ sudo rm /usr/bin/java
$ sudo ln -s /Library/Internet\ Plug-Ins/JavaAppletPlugin.plugin/Contents/Home/bin/java /usr/bin
```

.. to replace an incorrect symlink.  Now `java -version` reports version 1.7 and the process works.